# how to handle date & time when splitting string on ":"

Tags: python

I am processing a text file, reading line by line splitting it, and inserting it into a database.
each line goes like

> 3530000000000:100000431506294:Jean:Camargo:male::::Kefron:6/4/2018 12:00:00 AM::11/19

The problem is that it also splits the date-time and as a result it populates the wrong information in the database like in the image below.

[image]

my code goes like:

```
 with open(filename, encoding="utf-8") as f:
        counter = 0
        for line in f:
            data = line.split(':')
            
            id = str(counter)
            Phonenumber = data[0].strip()
            profileID = data[1].strip()
            firstname = data[2].strip()
            secondname = data[3].strip()
            gender = data[4].strip()
            LocationWhereLive = data[5].strip()
            LocationWhereFrom = data[6].strip()
            RelationshipStatus = data[7].strip()
            whereWork = data[8].strip()
            AccountCreationDate = data [9].strip()
            Email = data[10].strip()
            Birthdate = data [11].strip()
            
            
            
            
            
            mycursor = mydb.cursor()
            sql = mycursor.execute("insert into dataleads values ('"+id+"','"+Phonenumber+"','"+profileID+"','"+firstname+"','"+secondname+"','"+gender+"','"+LocationWhereLive+"','"+LocationWhereFrom+"','"+RelationshipStatus+"','"+whereWork+"','"+AccountCreationDate+"','"+Email+"','"+Birthdate+"')")
            mycursor.execute(sql)
       
            mydb.commit()
            
            counter += 1
```

Comment: you can split with spaces before splitting with `:`, on your example the data is as `<data> <time>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternative to splitting by spaces, you can also leverage the maxsplit argument in the split and rsplit methods:

```
def make_list(s):
    before = s.split(":", maxsplit= 9) # splits up to the date
    after = before[-1].rsplit(":", maxsplit= 2)  # splits the last part up to the date (from the right)
    return [*before[:-1], *after] # creates a list with both parts

s = "3530000000000:100000431506294:Jean:Camargo:male::::Kefron:6/4/2018 12:00:00 AM::11/19"

make_list(s)
Out: 
['3530000000000',
 '100000431506294',
 'Jean',
 'Camargo',
 'male',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 'Kefron',
 '6/4/2018 12:00:00 AM',
 '',
 '11/19']
```

Comment: beware: this will work great on the given input, but fail if any of the missing fields in the example can exist and contain `:` in other lines!

Comment: That is a valid caveat.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, you can split with the whitespace:

```
s = "3530000000000:100000431506294:Jean:Camargo:male::::Kefron:6/4/2018 12:00:00 AM::11/19"

split_s = s.split() # default split is any whitespace character

print(split_s[0]) # will print "3530000000000:100000431506294:Jean:Camargo:male::::Kefron:6/4/2018"
print(split_s[1]) # will print "12:00:00"
print(split_s[2]) # will print "AM::11/19"
```

Answer (score 1):

To deal with the original file, you can split this in a loop with knowledge of the count of fields, rather than trying to use how many separator characters there are

```py
collection = []

_line = line  # keep a backup of the line to compare and count blocks

for field_index in range(12):
    if field_index < 8:  # get the first 8 fields (or some set)
        prefix, _line = _line.split(":", 1)  # only split once!
        collection.append(prefix)
        continue
    if field_index == 9:  # match date field _line from regex
        if _line.startswith("::"):  # test if field was omitted
            _line = _line[1:]  # truncate the first character
            continue
        r"^\d+/..."  # TODO regex for field
        continue
    ...
```

This can be tuned or adapted to handle any field which can be

- absent
- also contain the separators in it (thanks)

---

However, if you can instead take a moment to educate the author of this file that it's problematic and why and nicely.. they may rewrite the file to be better for you or provide you with its input files you are further [munging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mung_(computer_term))

Specifically, the tool could either

- use a separator unavailable in the resulting data (such as `|` or `##SEPARATOR##`)
- escape the fields or swap their separators to another character before writing (`.replace(":", "-")`)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution is to match the field in the line first and transform it, allowing you to deal with the field on its own (perhaps transforming it back via a regex or `.replace()`)

```
line = re.sub(r"(\d\d?):(\d\d):(\d\d) (AM|PM)", r"\1-\2-\3-\4", line)
# now split out line on :
```

```py
>>> line = "3530000000000:100000431506294:Jean:Camargo:male::::Kefron:6/4/2018 12:00:00 AM::11/19"
>>> re.sub(r"(\d\d?):(\d\d):(\d\d) (AM|PM)", r"\1-\2-\3-\4", line).split(":")
['3530000000000', '100000431506294', 'Jean', 'Camargo', 'male', '', '', '', 'Kefron', '6/4/2018 12-00-00-AM', '', '11/19']
```

Answer (score 0):

The structure is the same you only join the split data back together again

```
counter = 0
line = "3530000000000:100000431506294:Jean:Camargo:male::::Kefron:6/4/2018 12:00:00 AM::11/19"
data = line.split(':')

id = str(counter)
Phonenumber = data[0].strip()
profileID = data[1].strip()
firstname = data[2].strip()
secondname = data[3].strip()
gender = data[4].strip()
LocationWhereLive = data[5].strip()
LocationWhereFrom = data[6].strip()
RelationshipStatus = data[7].strip()
whereWork = data[8].strip()
AccountCreationDate = data [9].strip() + ':' + data[10].strip() +":" + data[11].strip()
Email = data[12].strip()
Birthdate = data [13].strip()
```